# Move Excel Data Based On Date Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move data from a 5 column spread sheet in excel to other sub spread sheets based on one of the date columns in the first spread sheet.  The sub-spreadsheets will be created if they do not exist, otherwise they will be populated with data from the master spreadsheet. The spread sheets names will be a date that is the start of the week(being monday).  my columns are: Work Order, Description, Location, Asset, Date.

Example:

Work Order - Description - Location - Asset - Date

123   ----------      test&inspect - NC-231  -    KK32  - 8/21/14

In this example my master spreadsheet with a date row of 8/21/14 will create a subspread sheet with a name of 8/18/14 since this row falls in the week of 8/18/14 and insert the other columns with it. How can this be done inside of an excel workbook?

Comment: Can you add the code you've written so far to your question and let us know where you're having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date
Dim I as Date 

firstDate = Inputbox("What start date?") ' request your input for what date Monday is 
secondDate = DateAdd("d", 6, firstDate)

For Each Cell in Range("E2"),Range("E2").End(xldown)
   ActiveCell = Cell
     If cell => firstdate  and  =< secondate  then  ' test if falls under days of week     
            ActiveCell.Row.Copy    
            On error resume next      
            Worksheets.Add.Name = Firstdate
            Sheets(" & Firstdate &").Select 
            Range("A1").End(lxDown).Offset(1,0).pastespecial
 Next Cell  
End Sub
```

Not tested but should be a start .